# Porting Model Developed in SPark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have access to a Spark cluster where I have been asked to train a model. I am yet to learn the process, but I need to understand one thing before I even go down that path.

If I were to save the resulting model to disk, can I then I bring it over to my computer (just a PC) that has PySpark installed on top of a standard Anaconda Python distribution and score simple datasets using this saved model file? Will that approach work?

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works, I have been able to make it work, using pyspark 3.0.1 on a cluster and a local machine.

You can rely on [pipeline persistence function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#ml-persistence-saving-and-loading-pipelines)

Persist the pipeline:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
predictor = pipeline.fit(training_set)
predictor.save(path)
```

Pipeline will be persisted into a folder, you may want to tar it to get it back to your local machine. Then on your local machine:

```
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel
model = PipelineModel.load(path)
model.transform(df)
```

According to the documentation, you should be able to switch your model seemlessly between scala/java/python (and even R now). If you rely on different spark versions between your cluster and your local machine, I would advice you to read carefully the [backward compatibility documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#ml-persistence-saving-and-loading-pipelines).